# Search listview items using a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, listview, search

I am trying to make a search box for my listview and I managed to make an algorithm that works but not perfectly:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchBox.Text))
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in textureViewer.Items)
    {
        if (!item.Text.ToLower().Contains(searchBox.Text.ToLower()))
            textureViewer.Items.Remove(item);
    }
    if (textureViewer.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        textureViewer.Focus();
    }
}
else
    LoadTextures();
```

So far, it works, I can search for items and they are displayed well but, for example if I search for "sword_diamond" and then remove "_diamond" so now I have in my searchBox only "sword" , it won't show me all the "sword" textures because I have already deleted them from my listview so I'll have to delete everything from the searchBox so it will refresh.
I wanted to try to hide the items, store the info which items are hid and at each step when a letter is deleted to make them appear. Unfortunately, item.Visible is not available for me and I don't think it would be a good algorithm.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: What is the original source of the data? Are you deleting items from the ListView to remove items that did not match the search?

Comment: Yes, I remove items that did not match the search. My items are made of a picture and a name, all pictures are stored in an ImageList

Comment: But what is the original source of the data? Is it from a file? or a database? Or is it in memory-data that the user has just entered?

Comment: It is in memory-data, I scan a folder for all .png images and load them in the memory when I start the program

Comment: And you don't want to get the data every time from the filesystem for performance reasons, right?

Comment: What you need to do is to cache the data in memory using some data structure, and for each search, you would clear the listview, get the data from this memory structure and put them into the listview (after you filter them of course). I am assuming that the size of data is reasonable so that it can fit in memory, otherwise you should leave it at disk.

Comment: Right, there is a big number of images and it'll take too much time to load them every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the ListView to display the results of the search, not to store the original data.

To store the original data, put them in some collection, for example a `List<string>` in an instance variable.

And every time you search, you can use LINQ to filter the data and then you can put the results into the ListView.

Here is an example:

Assuming that you store the data in some instance variable `data`:

```
var results = data.Where(x => x.Contains("sword")).ToList();
```

And then you would use `results` to fill the list view.

This way, `data` would always contain the original data (unfiltered). And for each search, you calculate a new data set just to display it in the ListView.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to say that the pictures are stored in a List<Texture> and I use the listview just to show them, this might be what I am looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Save you images list in a field on form, then use it to filter, like that

```
private IEnumerable<string> textures;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textures = LoadTextures();
}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
    {
        FillListView(item => item.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()));

        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
            listView1.Focus();
    }
    else
        FillListView();
}

private void FillListView(Func<string, bool> filter = null)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    var items = filter == null ? this.textures : this.textures.Where(filter);
    foreach (var item in items)
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
}

private IEnumerable<string> LoadTextures()
{
    return Directory.GetFiles("path", "*.png");
}
```